# Upgrading flutter failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to upgrade my flutter using command `flutter upgrade`
but command is giving me an error

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:                                    
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/flutter-3.16-candidate.0                  
error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git did not send all necessary objects
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Please help

I want to upgrade my flutter version from 3.16.5 to the lates 3.19

Comment: The problem may be caused because you are in a **candidate** branch. Run command in cmd `flutter channel stable` then run `flutter upgrade`.
If this doesn't help, and you don't find a solution, you may do a fresh install, as a last resort.

Comment: flutter channel stable gives same error